# Reduction of vector fields - action diffeomorphism and formal series

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, dynamical-systems, control-theory

Consider the control system with state $q=(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3$ defined by
$$
\dot q = u_1F_1(q)+u_2F_2(q) 
$$
where $u_1,u_2$ are the control functions (measurable mappings) and $F_1,F_2$ are the vector fields defined by
$$
F_1 = \partial_x + (-15\,{x}^{2}y-5\,{y}^{3}+{x}^{2}-2\,yx+{y}^{2}+12\,y)\partial_z
$$
$$
F_2 = \partial_y
$$

Using the following actions on couple (F,G) of vector fields:

- action of a diffeomorphism $\varphi$ (change of coordinates): 
  $\varphi \cdot (F,G) = (\varphi_\ast(F), \varphi_\ast(G))$
- action of a formal power series $\alpha$ in x,y,z :
  $\alpha \cdot (F,G) = (\cos(\alpha) F +\sin(\alpha) G,-\sin(\alpha) F +\cos(\alpha) G)$,

I would like to transform the system into a new one where the new vector fields $\hat F_1,\hat F_2$  can be expressed as
$$
\hat F_1 = \partial_x + r(x,y)\partial_z
$$
$$
\hat F_2 = \partial_y +s(x,y) \partial_z
$$
where $r$ and $s$ are polynomials functions which doesn't contain any of the second order terms $x^2,y^2,xy$.
Moreover the transformation should let invariant $(0,0,0)$.

EDIT: In page 21 of the following article,

http://sci-hub.cc/10.1007/978-1-4612-5651-9_2

the author gave explicit transformation to remove those terms but it seems there is an error of computations.

Comment: What does $\partial_i$ mean, does it mean the time derivative of $i$, or something else?

Comment: ah yeah $(\partial_x,\partial_y,\partial_z)$ evaluted at point $p$ is the local basis of the tangent space of $\mathbb{R}^3$ at $p$, so
$\partial_i = \frac{\partial }{\partial i}$